# How do I output user_registered time in my correct timezone?

Tags: plugins, php, jquery, javascript, timestamp

I am currently using Wordpress, and an element of user_registered returns the time of registration of the user.
I have set the correct timezone, but don't know how to get the user_registered output to match my current time.
So far, this is what I have.

```
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');


    $users = get_users();

    foreach( $users as $user ) {

        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );

        $registered = $udata->user_registered;

        printf( '%s member since %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name, date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $registered ) ) );
    }


echo('date below <br>');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The date default timezone indeed changes the timezone (last echo)
However, what I want to change is the output of user_registered. (which is the stored time).

How do I globally change the way the time is being displayed when called? In other words if I call for the date/timestamp through plugin or direct, it will always give me the output of America/Los_Angeles.

Thanks in advance. I'm a noob. FYI the echo and printf stuff is purely for temporary display. I want to change the way user_registered is rendered when called from plugin or direct.

If javascript or jquery is an option i'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time offset from WordPress Settings using

```
get_option( 'gmt_offset' )
```

So I found the easiest method is to do this:

```
gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) . ' hours', strtotime( $udata->user_registered ) ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

On the **Settings > General** page, find the section labeled **Timezone**. Select a city in the same timezone as you.

Comment: This does not work for the User Table. The user_registered is always stored as UTC Time regardless of the Settings > General Timezone. You will need to convert the time yourself.